# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) in apply(boxcox)

Tags: r

I have a matrix of about 650 columns and for each column I want to find the optimal lambda for the boxcox transformation.
I want to use the function boxcox from the MASS package, which outputs two lists: $x$ is the list of possible lambdas, $y$ is the list of log-likelihood values for the given lambdas. The optimal lambda is the one that scores the highest likelihood.

I thought the following piece of code would work:

```
library(MASS)
optimal.lambda1 <- apply(mymatrix, 2, function (d) {
    boxcoxlist <- boxcox(lm(d~1), lambda=seq(-5,5,by=.1), plotit=F)
    p <- boxcoxlist$x[which.max(boxcoxlist$y)]
    return(p)
    }
)
```

Unfortunately I always get the same error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'd' not found
```

A similar error occours as well if I try a lapply version of it:

```
library(MASS)
optimal.lambda1 <- lapply(1:ncol(mymatrix), function (d) {
    boxcoxlist <- boxcox(lm(mymatrix[,d]~1), lambda=seq(-5,5,by=.1), plotit=F)
    p <- boxcoxlist$x[which.max(boxcoxlist$y)]
    return(p)
    }
)
```

Also, I tried to isolate the object function into something like

```
optimal.lambda2 <- function (d) {
    boxcoxlist <- boxcox(lm(d~1), lambda=seq(-5,5,by=.1), plotit=F)
    p <- boxcoxlist$x[which.max(boxcoxlist$y)]
    return(p)
    }
```

and then use it as an argument of (l)apply, but the second function alone returns the error too; i.e., the following command alone always returns the same error:

```
optimal.lambda2(mymatrix[,1])
```

Any suggestion about how to make it work?

Comment: You should also consider whether this is something that is worth doing. It may help you to read [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33320/7290), & [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3530/7290).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.